# How can I keep track of level when recursively mapping tree-structure array?

Tags: php, recursion

In order to build a breadcrumb menu, I need to convert the array `$exampleBreadcrumbMenu` into the form of `$exampleFlatArray`.

Basically I need to iterate through `$exampleBreadcrumbMenu` following each of the paths down as far as they go, building an array item for each menu item with the information in `$exampleFlatArray` for each menu item I find.

I've got recursion working well enough so I can process each item in the tree structure, but can't figure out how to maintain the right level number for each item.

The main code is in the main function below `$page->remap_breadcrumbmenu_to_flat_array()`.

```
   $exampleBreadcrumbMenu = ['Home' =>
        [
            'Projects' => [
                'Create Project',
                'View Project',
                'Delete Project',
                'Export Project',
                ['Advanced' => [
                        'Upgrade',
                        'Downgrade'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'Employees' => [
                'Create Employee',
                'View Employee',
                'Delete Employee',
                'Export Employee',
                ['Advanced' => [
                        'Upgrade',
                        'Downgrade'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'Settings' => [
                ['Front End' => [
                        'CSS',
                        'HTML',
                        'Colors'
                    ]
                ],
                ['Back End' => [
                        'Database',
                        'PHP',
                        'Colors'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'About',
            'Help'
        ]
    ];

    $exampleFlatArray = [
        ['home' => [
                'level' => 0,
                'title' => 'Home',
                'prelinks' => [],
                'sublinks' => [
                    ['projects' => 'Projects'],
                    ['employees' => 'Employees'],
                    ['settings' => 'Settings']
                ]
            ]
        ],
        ['projects' => [
                'level' => 1,
                'title' => 'Projects',
                'prelinks' => [
                    ['home' => 'Home']
                ],
                'sublinks' => [
                    ['createProject' => 'Create Project'],
                    ['viewProject' => 'View Project'],
                    ['deleteProject' => 'Delete Project'],
                    ['exportProject' => 'Export Project'],
                    ['advanced' => 'Advanced']
                ]
            ]
        ],
        etc.,
        etc.,
    ];
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
public function remap_breadcrumbmenu_to_flat_array($breadcrumbMenu, $key = '', $level = 0) {
    $flatArray = [];
    if (is_array($breadcrumbMenu)) {
        $key = $key == '' ? 'Home' : $key;
        echo 'MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ' . $key . ' (' . $level . ')<br/>';
        if (count($breadcrumbMenu) > 0) {
            foreach ($breadcrumbMenu as $key => $breadcrumbItem) {
                $this->remap_breadcrumbmenu_to_flat_array($breadcrumbItem, $key, ++$level);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(is_string($breadcrumbMenu)) {
            echo $breadcrumbMenu . ' (' . $level . ')<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

The recursion seems to be working ok, but the level isn't right:

> ```
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Home (0)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Projects (1)
> Create Project (2)
> View Project (3)
> Delete Project (4)
> Export Project (5)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Advanced (6)
> Upgrade (7)
> Downgrade (8)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Employees (2)
> Create Employee (3)
> View Employee (4)
> Delete Employee (5)
> Export Employee (6)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Advanced (7)
> Upgrade (8)
> Downgrade (9)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Settings (3)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Front End (4)
> CSS (5)
> HTML (6)
> Colors (7)
> MENU>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Back End (5)
> Database (6)
> PHP (7)
> Colors (8)
> About (4)
> Help (5)
> ```

Comment: Why home has prelinks?

Comment: @lolka_bolka sorry that was a mistake, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `++$level`, as it will also increase the local variable in the scope of the current level, meaning that you'll increase `$level` every iteration of your `foreach` loop within the same scope. Pass `$level + 1` to the recursive call.